# Different representations for complex conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis

In different textbooks, there are two representations for complex conjugate. Are they the same?
$$
\bar \omega (\bar \sigma )
$$
$$
\overline {\omega (\sigma )} 
$$

A textbook states the following:

> Consider functions analytic outside the unit circle, including at
> infinity  $$ f(\zeta ) = \frac{{{b_1}}}{\zeta } + \frac{{{b_2}}}{{{\zeta ^2}}} + \frac{{{b_3}}}{{{\zeta ^3}}} +  \cdots ,\quad \zeta  > 1 $$ Take its conjugate   $$ \bar f(\bar \zeta ) = \frac{{{{\bar b}_1}}}{{\bar \zeta }} + \frac{{{{\bar b}_2}}}{{{{\bar \zeta }^2}}} + \frac{{{{\bar b}_3}}}{{{{\bar \zeta }^3}}} +  \cdots ,\quad \zeta  > 1 $$

Should this be represented as  $\overline {f(\zeta )} $?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they are not. Assuming that $\omega$ is a complex-valued function and that $\sigma$ is a complex number, then:

- $\overline\omega\left(\overline\sigma\right)$ is the conjugate of $\omega\left(\overline\sigma\right)$;
- $\overline{\omega(\sigma)}$ is the conjugate of $\omega(\sigma)$.

In general, they are distinct.

Comment: That is incorrect.  $\bar{\omega}(\bar{\sigma})$ is defined as the value of function $\bar{\omega}$ evaluated at $\bar{\sigma}$, not the complex conjugate of $\omega(\bar{\sigma})$ (i.e., $\overline{\omega(\bar{\sigma})}$).

Comment: @user10354138 Isn't the function $\overline\omega$ the function $z\mapsto\overline{\omega(z)}$?